# Properties don't get the NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a little application with 3 files. The first file is `Authentication` that inherits from the second file `ObservableObject`. This file inherits `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
class Authentication : ObservableObject
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Auth = Visibility.Visible;
        Tab = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public void SetView()
    {
        Auth = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Tab = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public Visibility Auth { get; set; }
    public Visibility Tab { get; set; }
    public Visibility Admin { get; set; }
    public Visibility Planner { get; set; }
    public Visibility WorkPrep { get; set; }
    public Visibility Leader { get; set; }
    public Visibility PreSet { get; set; }
    public Visibility Measure { get; set; }
    public Visibility Worker { get; set; }
}
```

My 3rd file is the ViewModel of my View.

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private Authentication auth = new Authentication();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        LogIn = new RelayCommand(() => auth.SetView(), () => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)) ? false : true);
        auth.Start();
    }

    public ICommand LogIn { get; set; }
    public Visibility Auth
    {
        get
        {
            return auth.Auth;
        }
        set
        {
            auth.Auth = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public Visibility Tab
    {
        get
        {
            return auth.Tab;
        }
        set
        {
            auth.Tab = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I start the application `auth.Start();` is executed right and the correct `Visibility` is set. When I press the `Button` bound to the `Command` `LogIn`, `auth.SetView();` is executed but the `Visibilities` are not updated.

What my conclusion is that when I load the application, the `Visibilities` are set correct but once it's loaded it doesn't update from the `Authentication` class to the `MainWindowViewModel` class.

---

EDIT: Here is the `ObservableObject` class that might be important to this question.

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you validated your conclusion by debugging your code?

Comment: @DanielKelley, yes. I checked each variable and property that comes in play. When I call `auth.Start();` from `public MainWindowViewModel` the `Visibilities` are set correct. When I call auth.SetView() from the `LogIn Command` (or a regular button click, doesn't matter), the 2 properties in the `Authentication` class are set but not in the `MainWindowViewModel` class which uses the values from the `Authentication`.

Comment: @DanielKelley, just wondering. Would it be "smarter" to just do the visual stuff in `MainWindowViewModel` and the logical stuff in `Authentication`? Then use an event (any other option) from `Authentication` to set the properties in `MainWindowViewModel` directly? I know it works if I set the properties in `MainWindowViewModel` while the application is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You update Auth's visisbility through the Authentication class, that doesn't cause the NotifyProperty event from being fired. I added a call to NotifyPropertyChanged method inside the Authentication class:

```
class Authentication : ObservableObject
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Auth = Visibility.Visible;
        Tab = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public void SetView()
    {
        Auth = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Tab = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private Visibility auth;
    public Visibility Auth
    {
        get
        {
            return auth;
        }
        set
        {
            auth= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Visibility tab;
    public Visibility Tab
    {
        get
        {
            return tab;
        }
        set
        {
            tab = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    // etc
}
```

Now, we just echo every NotifyProperty event in MainWindowViewModel (this should be sufficient in this case).

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private Authentication auth = new Authentication();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        LogIn = new RelayCommand(() => auth.SetView(), () => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)) ? false : true);

        // Echo the PropertyChanged events from our auth class
        auth.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }

        auth.Start();
    }

    public ICommand LogIn { get; set; }
    public Visibility Auth
    {
        get
        {
            return auth.Auth;
        }
        set
        {
            auth.Auth = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public Visibility Tab
    {
        get
        {
            return auth.Tab;
        }
        set
        {
            auth.Tab = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added my `ObservableObject` code to the original post. Your suggestion is correct but is not the problem in this case.

Comment: YES, IT IS! You are basically not providing it with a property name (hence the default value `propertyName = ""`) which makes it not work at all. Change the implementation of `Auth` to what I have suggested and it should work properly.

Comment: Before I start to argue, you better check my code of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It uses `[CallerMemberName]` from `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`. This gets the property's name and fills it in without me having to put the property's name when I call that method. `CallerMemberName` it description is as follows: `Allows you to obtain the method or property name of the caller to the method.`

Comment: My bad, I totally ignored that. But hey, I probably found the issue now, check my updated answer. Correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: Tnx for the reply. I'll check it tomorrow and let you know how it went.

Comment: when I try to add `auth.PropertyChanged += this.PropertyChanged;` to `public MainWindowViewModel()` I get the following error: `This event can only appear on the left side of += or -=.`